# Computing modulus by hand

Tags: number-theory, modular-arithmetic

Can someone please explain how you would compute the following modulus by hand?

7503 mod 81

-7503 mod 81

Comment: Modulus by hand?  Were you never taught long division?

Comment: Do you understand the definition of mod? I would suggest first understanding that by seeing "simpler" examples; for examples what is $5$ mod $2$? What is $6$ mod $3$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First note that $81=9^2=3^4$.

$3$ divides $7503$ as the sum of its digits is $15$.

Simplify by $3$: using $75=60+15$ we get $7503 = 3\cdot 2501$. If we find the remainder $r$ of $2501$ mod $27$ then $7503$ mod $81=3r$ will be.

Now, as $2501=2700-199$ and $199=270-71$ and $71=81-10$, we have
$$2501=2700-(270-(81-10))=\ 27x-10$$
which can also be written as $27(x-1)+17$.

So, $7503$ mod $81\ =\ 3\cdot 17\ $ and $\,-7503$ mod $81\ = 3\cdot 10$.

Answer (score 3):

This is so simple that it can be done not only *manually* but *mentally*!

$\begin{eqnarray}{\rm mod}\ 81\!:\, &&\color{#c00}{75}(\color{blue}{100})+3\\ 
\equiv\, && \!\color{#c00}{-6}\,\ (\color{blue}{19})+3,\ \ {\rm by}\,\ \ \color{#c00}{75\equiv -6},\ \ \color{blue}{100\equiv 19}\\
\equiv\, &&\!-111 \, \equiv\, {-}30
\end{eqnarray}$

Comment: How did you get the last line to be -30?

Comment: @user3064097 $\ {\rm mod}\ \color{#c00}{81}\!:\,\ {-}111\,\equiv\, -111\!+\!\color{#c00}{81} \,\equiv\, -30\,\equiv\, -30+\color{#c00}{81}\,\equiv\, 51.\ $ More generally it is true $ $ that:  $\,\ n\,\equiv\, n + \color{#c00}{81}\, k.\ \ $

Comment: Looks clear enough to me. I hereby cancel one of the downvotes. By the way, the ten percent of the male population that is colorblind in one form or another might have difficulty seeing your distinctions (though you use them to good advantage). Red (and blue) are your safest choices; green isn't.

Comment: @Rick Thanks for the feedback. Please *do* let me know if something is not clear so that I can improve it to make it as accessible as possible. I'm still not sure what was problematic in the earlier version, but I'd really like to know so that I can avoid any such stumbling blocks in future answers.